# java RMI + source hitting server is from internet or from intranet

Tags: java, sockets, rmi

In java RMI i am building a chat application. But i am not able to figure out a way to find out, whether the IP which is hitting my server is from my internal organization network(INTRANET) or from external world(INTERNET). 
Right now i am using

```
try {
        System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname",InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress());
        Registry statusRegistry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(ChatConstants.statusPort);
        ChatInterface chat = new ChatImpl(ChatConstants.statusPort) ;
        statusRegistry.rebind("statusconnection",chat);
        System.out.println("RMIStatusConnection Server is started...");
     } catch (RemoteException e) {
            System.out.println("RMIStatusConnection failed...");
            e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try RemoteServer.getClientHost(), but it may only provide the address of the nearest NAT device.

NB there's not much point in setting java.rmi.server.hostname like that. That's the default. You only need to set it if there's something wrong with the default setting.